# Problem with Google Cloud Pub/Sub API and Spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-pubsub

I write spring boot application for subscribing Google cloud Pub/Sub topic for this I use Google's [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub-integration/index.html?index=..%2F..index#5), but when I run application I have get this error

```html
2019-02-02 18:03:10.248  INFO 15080 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2019-02-02 18:03:10.271  INFO 15080 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-02-02 18:03:10.610 ERROR 15080 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of method messageChannelAdapter in tech.garoon.cloud.CloudApplication required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

How Can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration** provides autoconfiguration feature of creating necessary beans including PubSubTemplate. In your case, somethng is missed, Kindly ensure that dependencies are in place or recreate following bean to make it work.

```
    @Bean
    public PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate(PubSubPublisherTemplate pubSubPublisherTemplate,
            PubSubSubscriberTemplate pubSubSubscriberTemplate) {
        return new PubSubTemplate(pubSubPublisherTemplate, pubSubSubscriberTemplate);
    }
```

Additionally, make sure **GcpContextAutoConfiguration** is created based on below properties in application.properties.

```
spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=${gcp_credentials}
```

**starter dependency**:

```
      <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer I missed add one dependency. ))

`implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:1.1.0.RELEASE'`

Comment: it is part of gcp-starter-pubsub. If above answer helped you, kindly accept it.

Comment: . I have all the dependencies. I can even import GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration. Still doesn't work. Still get No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.gcp.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate' available.

Comment: For me, it started giving errors for PubSubTemplate, PubSubPublisherTemplate, and PublisherFactory after adding a custom bean definition. Any other solution you got in the meantime?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Manually initializing the beans didn't help, because each time another dependency was missing (PubSubTemplate, PubSubPublisherTemplate and PublisherFactory etc.).

My troubles started when I wanted to upgrade Spring from 2.7.10 to 3.0.9.

Make sure you have both dependencies defined inside **dependencyManagement** in **pom.xml** - if not, add them.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>2022.0.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

I added this dependency

```
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:1.1.0.RELEASE'
```

My dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-pubsub:1.1.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-autoconfigure:1.1.0.RELEASE'
    implementation "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:2.1.2.RELEASE"
    implementation 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.1.2.RELEASE'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if using external configuration class that is registering your channels, message handlers etc, make sure to annotate the configuration class with `@Import({GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class})`

```
@Configuration
@Import({GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class})
public class PubSubConfig{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue with these versions of spring-boot and spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pub:

```
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.8.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

and in my application.properties I had
`spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.enabled=false` for local development.
I removed `spring.cloud.gcp.pubsub.enabled=false` and it worked. Although now it creates a connection to the pubsub gcp topic, so for local development, you will need to comment out publishing, to avoid sending messages.

Answer (score 0):

### [THE ANSWER IN ANOTHER THREAD THIS IS BASED ON](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68486536/8876886)

See the above for more detail, I won't bother to re-author it all as the poster there did a good job dictating the issue.

To raise out more specifically the solve, in my case this was an issue with using the `org.springframework.cloud` provided artifacts instead of the `com.google.cloud` ones. When I swapped to the latter the `GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration` kicked into gear as expected

I think whether this is a solution for you will matter what version of Spring/Spring Boot you use. See these blog posts which talk about the matter:

- https://spring.io/blog/2019/07/24/simplifying-the-spring-cloud-release-train
- https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/spring-cloud-gcp/reference/html/index.html#migration-guide-from-spring-cloud-gcp-1-x-to-2-x