# No qualifying bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.publisher.PubSubPublisherTemplate'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have an application that uses Pub/Sub on GCP. Subscribing works without an issue however whenever I add

private final PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate;

I get get an error that reads

```
Error creating bean with name 'pubSubTemplate' defined in ut.importer.eventprocessor.EventApplication: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'pubSubTemplate' parameter 0: No qualifying bean of type 'com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.publisher.PubSubPublisherTemplate' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}
```

I know that the pubsubTemplate should come with the dependency but I added the bean anyway thinking it could be clashing with another dependency

```
@Bean
@Primary
public PubSubTemplate pubSubTemplate(PubSubPublisherTemplate pubSubPublisherTemplate,
                                     PubSubSubscriberTemplate pubSubSubscriberTemplate) {
    return new PubSubTemplate(pubSubPublisherTemplate, pubSubSubscriberTemplate);
}
```

However this did not work, I received the same error.

Then I tried

```
@Import({GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration.class})
```

with both imports

```
import org.springframework.cloud.gcp.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration;
```

and

```
import com.google.cloud.spring.autoconfigure.pubsub.GcpPubSubAutoConfiguration;
```

And still received the same error.

pom.xml

```
<spring-cloud.version>2023.0.0</spring-cloud.version>
<spring-cloud-gcp.version>5.1.0</spring-cloud-gcp.version>
```

---

```
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-gcp.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-starter-pubsub</artifactId>
        </dependency>

      < added spring gcp autoconfig but it had no effect - removed>
```

---

```
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.PubSubTemplate;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.publisher.PubSubPublisherTemplate;
import com.google.cloud.spring.pubsub.core.subscriber.PubSubSubscriberTemplate;
```

Reading the documentation one of these above solutions should have worked. Has anyone had a similar issue or any suggestions on something else to try?

Comment: Have you added spring.cloud.gcp.credentials.location=${gcp_credentials} into application.properties?
Can you show, where have you added these imports ?Maybe this link will be useful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54493983/problem-with-google-cloud-pub-sub-api-and-spring-boot-application

Comment: @MyWay yes I read that one and several others. I also do have the `gcp_credentials` added.

Comment: @MyWay I have tried everything I can think of. However as soon as I bring in `PubSubTemplate` to publish it will not work. I get the missing bean error. I create the bean and don't autowire `PubSubTemplate` anywhere I still get it. However subscribing works with no issue.